# How to insert data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What the problem on my coding? I cannot insert data to ms sql.. I'm using C# as front end and MS SQL as databases...

```
name = tbName.Text;
userId = tbStaffId.Text;
idDepart = int.Parse(cbDepart.SelectedValue.ToString());

string saveStaff = "INSERT into tbl_staff (staffName,userID,idDepartment) " +
                   " VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + userId +"', '" + idDepart + "');";

SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(saveStaff);

try
{
querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch
{
//Error when save data

MessageBox.Show("Error to save on database");
openCon.Close();
Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
}
```

Comment: You didn't type `22', 1); DELETE FROM tbl_staff; --` exactly right in your `tbStaffId` TextBox. Once you've done this, read up on SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for help..

When i run a program, this error i get..

"ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized."

Comment: Please, please parameterize this!

Comment: Sorry... im newbie in C#.. Can someone explain me, what functions for parametes?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to set Connection property of Command object and use parametersized query instead of hardcoded SQL to avoid [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
 using(SqlConnection openCon=new SqlConnection("your_connection_String"))
    {
      string saveStaff = "INSERT into tbl_staff (staffName,userID,idDepartment) VALUES (@staffName,@userID,@idDepartment)";

      using(SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(saveStaff))
       {
         querySaveStaff.Connection=openCon;
         querySaveStaff.Parameters.Add("@staffName",SqlDbType.VarChar,30).Value=name;
         .....
         openCon.Open();

         querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks my friends... is Done!

Sorry im newbie in C#...:)

Comment: Sorry... im newbie in C#.. what functions for parametes?

Comment: To avoid [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @Chuki2: note that this correct answer does not have a try/catch block, and _does_ have `using` blocks. You should follow this example.

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders, i will do your suggestion...:)

Comment: An explicit Close() is not needed on a connection object that is in a using clause

Comment: `.AddWithValue()` is recommended.

Comment: I get why an explicit Close() is not needed with `using`, but I don't understand why a try-catch is not needed either (according to @JohnSaunders 's comment).

Comment: @Floella Because you should almost never use a try/catch block. I don't have time to educate you on proper exception handling, but here's a thought process you can use. Pretend there is no exception handling at all in the program. Now, what's the worst that could happen? You know that an exception in a method will "bubble up" to the caller of the method if not handled. So if there's no exception handling, any exception will bubble up to the top level of your program, and will probably terminate the process. If you use `using` blocks properly, you will have no lost resources.

Comment: @Floella OTOH your end users won't see a friendly error message from the exception, and the exception may not be logged to help in troubleshooting. So, at the outermost layers in your program, you want a try/catch block to log the exception, and maybe to say "sorry, we got some kind of error" to the end user. So, in general, use as little exception handling as possible to still meet your requirements. Having try/catch blocks at every level is the worst thing you can do. You'll have better results doing nothing at all, then adding exception handling only where absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Floella Finally, a hint. When I first start working on a piece of code, one of the first things I'll do is check to see if there is too much exception handling. If too much, I make a copy of the code and I remove almost all try/catch blocks. I then ask a team lead, "please tell me why the code isn't better off with no exception handling?" Sometimes there's a good answer to that question. Most often, there isn't.

Comment: @adatapost please verify my edit that added missing `querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();` (without it you get copy-pastes that don't work like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661745/how-to-transfer-data-from-a-class-to-an-sql-serer-table#58661745)

Answer (score 36):

I think you lack to pass `Connection` object to your `command` object. and it is much better if you will use `command` and `parameters` for that.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;            // <== lacking
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = "INSERT into tbl_staff (staffName, userID, idDepartment) VALUES (@staffName, @userID, @idDepart)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staffName", name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idDepart", idDepart);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            // error here
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry... im newbie in C#.. what functions for parametes?

Comment: I think the finally is not required, the purpose of a using statement is to dispose of the connection even in the event of an exception https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx, am I missing something?

Answer (score -5):

```
string saveStaff = "INSERT into student (stud_id,stud_name) " + " VALUES ('" + SI+ "', '" + SN + "');";
cmd = new SqlCommand(saveStaff,con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This one is open to SQL injection attack. You should use Command.Parameters for the parameters.

Comment: Avoid this example. As S.L.Barth mentioned, this practice is open to SQL injections