# my code gets this error:One or more errors occurred during processing of command

Tags: oracle, connection

I have problem with running this:
  [image: my error]

i captured picture from my win

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=DATA;Password=ss8_pakhsh;User ID=SHIFTS_N";
con.Open();
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO GROUPS(GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME,DEPT_ID) " +                                  
                    "VALUES(SEQ_MAX_GROUP_ID_NO.NEXTVAL,@groupName,SELECT
                    DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE 
                    DEPARTMENT_NAME=@depName)";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlcommand, con);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@groupName", textBox1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depName", comboBox1.SelectedItem);
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
oda.Fill(dt);
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();
```

Comment: your sqlcommand string seems to be wrong.

Comment: @FatemehHojjati simply you can put try catch block .So you can see what is going on

Comment: which catch do u mean?

Comment: [Have a look here John Woo answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241084/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

Change the sqlcommand string as shown below,

```
string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO GROUPS(GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME,DEPT_ID) " +                                  
                    "VALUES(SEQ_MAX_GROUP_ID_NO.NEXTVAL,@groupName,SELECT "+
                    "DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE "+
                    "DEPARTMENT_NAME=@depName)";
```

This should solve the issue.

Observation: It is not a good practice to directly set the textBox1.Text value in parameter.

Comment: can you update the question with the code you have in your pc?

Comment: i mean in my code the query is right,when i copy it here lines changes,and my query is correct

Comment: Can you see the inner exception and find out the root cause of the issue?

Comment: can i send picture of this for you ?through email

Comment: you can attach the inner exception image in this question itself, so that others who are interested to answer will be able to look at it.

Comment: In the exception dialog, click on 'view Detail...' link and look at the inner exception. It will give you more details of the exception.

Comment: inner exception is null