# Two common errors prevent this website to work correctly

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is a very simple website that the user fills the inputs and can save them in sql database and can send an email too. However I got two errors,this is the first:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users...\Desktop\Dpp2012New\App_Data\dppdatabase.mdf failed. A
>   database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\Users...\Desktop\Dpp2012New\App_Data\dppdatabase.mdf failed. A
>   database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

And this is the second one:

> Unhandled Exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

that shows :

> incorrect syntax near '('. sql

which gets to code `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Below is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio     2015\WebSites\WebSite4\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier");
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "save ('"+txtName.Text+"','"+txtLtName.Text+"','"+compName.Text+"','"+address0ne.Text+"','"+addressTwo.Text+"','"+cityName.Text+"','"+reionName.Text+"','"+postCode.Text+"','"+countryName.Text+"','"+emailAddress.Text+"')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }

    protected void TextBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I have tried some solutions but they didn't work.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO your_table_name(Name, LtName, CompName, AdOne,
AdTwo, City, ReionName, PostCode, CountryName, EmailAddr)
Values(@Name, @LtName, @CompName, @AdOne, @AdTwo, @City, @ReionName, 
@PostCode, @CountryName, @EmailAddr");

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LtName", LtName.Text);
```

etc...

Answer (score -1):

Is this an insert or Update statement?
At am minimum, You should user parameters in your sql...
but you should also use the using statement

Comment: It just saves the information so is an insertion(I guess cuz Im beginner in c#).next time that the page reloads we can add data again.

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of your question.would you mind explain it more?

Comment: whats your table look like?

Comment: It has a name column with data type and allow null. You mean this?

Comment: Check this link out...should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241084/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server