# How convert this function PHP in c#?

Tags: c#, php

I'm studying some codes of `Php` and `C#` and would like to know how can I convert this code in `C#`?

```
$data = {
    //field name in the database, amount to be inserted
    'name'   => 'myName',
    'email'  => 'myEmail',
    'number' => 9999999999
};

function DBCreate($table, array $data, $ReturnId = false){
    //table prefix
    $table  = DB_PREFIX . '_' . $table;

    //clean sql injection
    $data   = DBEscape($data);
    //creates an array based on database fields
    $fields = implode(',', array_keys($data));
    $values = "'".implode("', '", $data)."'";
    //query sql
    $query = "INSERT INTO {$table} ( {$fields} ) VALUES ( {$values})";
    //call function that executes the query
    return DBExecute($query, $ReturnId);
}
```

This code inserts data into any database table passing only the table name along with an array this array consists of pairs where the `key` is the field name in the database and the `value` is the value to be inserted into the database, last parameter is if necessary to recover the value of the `ID` entered in the database.

or which elements can study in order to convert?

yet got it:

```
 void DBCreate(string table, Dictionary<string,string> Data) {
    var fields = string.Join(", ",Data.Keys.ToArray());
    var values = string.Join(", ",Data.Values.ToArray());

    string sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ( " + fields + " ) VALUES ( " + values + " )";

    print(sql);     
 }
```

using:

```
 var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
        {"Name", "MeuName"},
        {"Passowrd", "mypass"}
 };
    DBCreate("tabela", myDictionary);
```

this is **Usuario** class:

```
public string       Name = "";   
public string       Passowrd = "";
public DateTime     Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1991");
public string       Email = "";
public string       Username = "";
public int          Cash = 0;
public int          GP = 0;
public string       IdCell = "";
```

how I can get all the names of the variables of the Usuario class, or how could I convert it into a list?

I decided:

```
BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | 
BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
BindingFlags.Instance | 
BindingFlags.Static;

Usuario user = new Usuario();

user.setName("Something");
user.setEmail(123456789);

var newUser = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(Usuario).GetFields(bindingFlags))
{
      print(field.Name + " Values => " + field.GetValue(user).ToString());
      newUser.Add(field.Name, field.GetValue(user).ToString());
}
```

thank you all!

Comment: this is not a translation service

Comment: You might do well by learning about [strings in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) and [ADO.NET fundamentals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx).

Comment: Could you at least explain what this does and someone may give you a way to do it without knowing PHP well.

Comment: What is usuario class here?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman i add the Usuario class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to keep the ordered map that PHP uses as an array? Since PHP uses an ordered associative array you might be able to use something like an [ordered dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) that is provided in .NET, or a list of [key value pairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx). The rest of it is escaping the values and building strings. You will have to explicitly define the return type.

Comment: yes, so I need to convert the object into a Dicionary , this will help me a lot ! thnk

Comment: For future reference, quoting from links / some code examples are usually good in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems the code is building up a table name and an insert query with multiple value pairs.
I don't do C# but it should be quit easy with some research on "insert sql c#". e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241084/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server) is first result I found.

Comment: I have an object that each attribute is the name of the respective table field in the database , I'm looking for ways to convert this object into an array , but without success I have a data entry function using `Parameters.Add` more I did not want to write all `query's`