# Difficulty Inserting Data from C# form into a Database

Tags: c#, database

I've just started learning C# using Visual Studio 2015, and my task is to create a lottery program that saves the generated numbers into a database. I've tried various methods and none of them seem to make any additions to my table. Can anyone help me understand what I need to do take an Integer that has been generated and converted into a string/ textbox and then insert that value into my table.

Heres my current code below, button 2 being the button I am trying to use to save the data from the textboxes with.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Database details
        string connectionString;
        SqlConnection connection;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Settings.LottoConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int[] slot = new int[6];
            int counter = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < slot.Length; i++)
            {
                slot[i] = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            }

            //Converting generated ints to Strings for display
            textBox1.Text = (slot[0].ToString());
            textBox2.Text = (slot[1].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (slot[2].ToString());
            textBox4.Text = (slot[3].ToString());
            textBox5.Text = (slot[4].ToString());
            textBox6.Text = (slot[5].ToString());

            //Incrementing Counter checks matches
            if (numericUpDown1.Value == slot[0])
            {
                counter += 1;
            }
            if (numericUpDown2.Value == slot[1])
            {
                counter += 1;
            }
            if (numericUpDown3.Value == slot[2])
            {
                counter += 1;
            }
            if (numericUpDown4.Value == slot[3])
            {
                counter += 1;
            }
            if (numericUpDown5.Value == slot[4])
            {
                counter += 1;
            }
            if (numericUpDown6.Value == slot[5])
            {
                counter += 1;
            }

            //display total matches
            textBox7.Text = ("You got" + counter + "/6 matches!");

           LottoDataSetTableAdapters.ResultsTableAdapter resultsTableAdapter =
            new LottoDataSetTableAdapters.ResultsTableAdapter();

            resultsTableAdapter.Insert((slot[0].ToString()), (slot[1].ToString()), (slot[2].ToString()), (slot[3].ToString()), (slot[4].ToString()), (slot[5].ToString()));
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Adding Data to Database
            string query = "INSERT INTO Results VALUES (@First)";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Second", textBox2.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Third", textBox3.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fourth", textBox4.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fifth", textBox5.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sixth", textBox6.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the definition of your Results table.  Is the results table a single column?

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT statement is missing the other parameters in the VALUES portion.  You also need to execute the command and you were missing brackets for the using of the connection.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Adding Data to Database
    string query = "INSERT INTO Results (First, Second, Third, Fourth, Fifth, Sixth) VALUES (@First, @Second, @Third, @Fourth, @Fifth, @Sixth)";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", textBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Second", textBox2.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Third", textBox3.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fourth", textBox4.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fifth", textBox5.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sixth", textBox6.Text);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot of sense. The only issue I have now is that when it reaches the command.ExecuteNonQuery(); It gives me an unhandled error  caused by Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. As far as I am aware my Coloumns are "First" "Second" etc. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please get the table definition from sql server?  If the column names truly are first, second, third... then I need to change my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect a table with six columns.  You may need to change this or the table definition based on your needs.

Comment: The names reflected in the properties in the SQL server are "First" "Second" etc.

Comment: Okay the Code now runs, however the table in my server explorer does not reflect any new additions. Is there some other location I should be looking to confirm that it is inserting the values into the database?

Comment: What is the connection string in your config file?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this question as been asked and answered before - have a look here - [How to insert data into SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241084/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server)

edit - my first impression was wrong, I can't see where you are executing your query against the db. its been a while since it have written ado code manual without using an orm so forgive me if i am wrong.