# How to connect this project with sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlconnection

`executenonquery()` error c#
this is how my code looks like

```
con.Open();

String name = textBox1.Text.ToString();
String address = textBox2.Text.ToString();

String id = textBox3.Text.ToString();
int iid = Int32.Parse(id);

String semester = textBox4.Text.ToString();
int i_sem = Int32.Parse(semester);

String field = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

String qry = "insert into Table values('" + name + "','" + address + "'," + iid + "," + i_sem + ",'" + field + "',)";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`executenonquery()` always makes me problem !

```
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I can see multiple issues already, but please share the issue you want us to fix. We don't know what error message you've got...

Comment: Your SQL is wrong. there is `,` in end

Comment: When i press insert button to store files in sql table it says.... System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near Table values !

Comment: Please update the question with those error information

Comment: what is your tablename? seems like you need to update TABLE with your tablename in the insert script.

Comment: table name is Table

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix a couple of things:

1. Remove the last `,` in your query.
2. I don't know if you have a table named **Table** in your database but you should check if the name is correct.
3. When you don't know how to correct your code it's better use the **try-catch** statement to understand where the real problem is in your code. [Here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)  about how to handle SQL exception in C# code.
4. You are getting **SqlException** because your query syntax is wrong but there is another way to add SQL parameters into your query without need to use a string variable. You could use the `SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue(String, Object)` method to achieve the same result and avoid **SQL Injection**:

```cs
command.Connection = connection;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "INSERT into YourTableName (name, address, id, semester, field) VALUES (@name, @address, @id, @semester, @field)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", iid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", i_sem);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field", field);

try
{
    connection.Open();
    int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(SqlException)
{
    // error here
}
finally
{
    connection.Close(); //close your connection if you do not need to keep it open
}
```

**More info:**

- [AddWithValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [SQL Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms161953(v=sql.105))
- [Other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241084/how-to-insert-data-into-sql-server) related to this topic